# Unwanted additional/current matplotlib window while embedding in tkinter gui

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm plotting streamed data with tkinter but my app opens the current plot in an additional window:

[image]

My App looks something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button_run = tk.Button(master=self, text='run', bg='grey', command=self.run)
        self.button_run.pack()
        self.fig = plt.Figure()
        self.fig, self.axes_dict = plt.subplot_mosaic([['o', 'o'], ['_', '__']])
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure=self.fig, master=self)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()
        self.fig.canvas.flush_events()

    def run(self):
        S = Streamer(parent=self)
        S.start()
```

And I stream data like this:

```
class Streamer:  

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def start(self):
    # plot random data
        for x in range(6):
            self.parent.axes_dict['o'].add_patch(Rectangle((x, randint(x, x*2)), height=0.4, width=0.4))
            self.parent.axes_dict['o'].relim()
            self.parent.axes_dict['o'].autoscale_view(True, True, True)
            self.parent.fig.canvas.draw_idle()
            self.parent.fig.canvas.flush_events()
            plt.pause(0.4)
```

Starting the app:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = App()
    A.mainloop()
```

How can I close this matplotlib window and why does it appear?

Comment: As I understood:--   If you want only one main window then you just need to remove the ```plt.pause(0.4)``` from the ```Streamer class``` ...And you are missing one ```=``` in starting the app it should be like ```if __name__ == '__main__':```

Comment: This didn't solve it in my case the matplotlib window is still appearing but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call `plt.pause()` because it will block the event loop of the `tkinter`.

Do like this using the `after()`.

```
class Streamer:
    ...
    def start(self):
        xs = list(range(6))
        def update():
            if xs:
                x = xs.pop(0)
                parent = self.parent
                parent.axes_dict['o'].add_patch(Rectangle((x, randint(x, x*2)), height=0.4, width=0.4))
                parent.axes_dict['o'].relim()
                parent.axes_dict['o'].autoscale_view(True, True, True)
                parent.fig.canvas.draw()
                parent.after(400, update)
        update()
```

If you do a time consuming work in the `update()`, you are better to use a worker thread or process.